# Criticism, please: simplifying state space model

Tags: model-selection, stochastic-processes, arma, volatility-forecasting, state-space-models

As a little experiment, I am extending a nice, interpretable AR/MA relationship between a security $r$ that is variably influenced by the previous $k$ time points over another security $f$.  These relationships ("lags") are represented by $l$.  I want to pump up the "realism" by making both securities move with stochastic volatility:

$
\begin{bmatrix} r_t \\ 
f_t \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} l_{r,1} & ... & l_{r,k} \\
l_{f,1} & ... & l_{f,k} \end{bmatrix} \Theta_t 
+ \Sigma_t u
$

$u \sim N(0,1)$

$
\log(\Sigma_t) = 
\begin{bmatrix} \log(\sigma_{r,t}) \\
\log(\sigma_{f,t}) \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \phi_r \\
1 & \phi_t \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix} \omega_r & \omega_f \\
\log(\sigma_{r,t-1}) & \log(\sigma_{r,t-1}) \end{bmatrix} 
+ \begin{bmatrix} \eta_{r,t} \\
\eta_{f,t}) \end{bmatrix} 
$

$\eta_{i,t} \sim N(0,\sigma_{\eta_i})$

$
\Theta_t = 
\begin{bmatrix} f_t \\
f_{t-1} \\
... \\ 
f_{t-k} \end{bmatrix} = 
I 
\begin{bmatrix} f_{t-1} \\
f_{t-2} \\
... \\ 
f_{t-k-1} \end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{f,t-1} \\
\sigma_{f,t-2} \\
... \\ 
\sigma_{f,t-k-1} \end{bmatrix}
$

1. Does this look right to better trained eyes, before I whip out a prototype?  Especially, suggestions on parameters that might to be worth consolidating (i.e., params not adding much explanatory "value")?
2. Any suggestions for how to approach the "lag" selection more rigorously (e.g., model selection procedure)?
3. Does anyone see shortcuts for consolidating the two transition equations ($\log(\Sigma_t)$ and $\Theta_t$) into the typical "state space representation," i.e., the $\Theta$, $F$, $G$, $V$, $W$ referred to in the literature.  For some special cases the equations can be simplified substantially: e.g., traditional MA log volatility models, a log transformation of the master equation simplifies out that pesky $u$ stochastic term.

Comment: P.S., if I do not hear anything within the next few days, I may x-post on http://quant.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Please don't crosspost in that case; just flag it to be migrated. :-)

Comment: @cardinal flag does not support quant.stackexchange (prob bc it is still beta).  Mind migrating it?  Thanks,